# Fallback / default value for @BindsInstance object

Tags: java, dagger-2

```java
// Previously, our Api looks like this:
@Component(modules = ApiManagerModule.class)
public interface ApiComponent {
  
  @Component.Builder
  interface Builder {
    ApiComponent build();
  }

  ApiManager apiManager();
}

@Module
public interface ApiManagerModule {
  @Binds
  ApiManager bindApiManager(ApiManagerImpl impl);
}

// User uses our API like:
ApiComponent apiComponent = 
    DaggerApiComponent.builder().build();
ApiManager apiManager = apiComponent.apiManager();
apiManager.doApiThings();
```

For some reason, we want to add an option object to our api. We made following changes:

```java
@Component(modules = ApiManagerModule.class)
public interface ApiComponent {
  
  @Component.Builder
  interface Builder {
    ApiComponent build();
    
    // **new**
    @BindsInstance
    Builder setApiOptions(ApiOptions options);
  }

  ApiManager apiManager();
}

@Module
public interface ApiManagerModule {
  @Binds
  ApiManager bindApiManager(ApiManagerImpl impl);
}

// **new**
@AutoValue
public abstract class ApiOptions {
  //...
  
  @AutoValue.Builder
  public abstract static class Builder {
    //...
  }
}

// User will now use our Api like:
ApiComponent apiComponent = DaggerApiComponent.builder()
    .setApiOptions(
        ApiOptions.builder()
            /*setters*/
            .build());
ApiManager apiManager = apiComponent.apiManager();
apiManager.doApiThings();
```

However, one issue is this is a breaking change. Users already integrated to our API has to make changes to set the @BindsInstance option object.

My question is, is it possible to provide fallback value for the `@BindsInstance` option object? We want to have something like this:

```java
ApiComponent apiComponent = 
    DaggerApiComponent.builder()
    // when `setApiOptions()` is not called, a default ApiOptions is created and provided.
    .build();
ApiManager apiManager = apiComponent.apiManager();
apiManager.doApiThings();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make [`@BindsInstance` `@Nullable`](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/BindsInstance.html):

> For builders, `@BindsInstance` methods must be called before building the component, unless their parameter is marked `@Nullable`, in which case the component will act as though it was called with a `null` argument. Primitives, of course, may not be marked `@Nullable`.

At that point you would need to `@Inject` a `@Nullable ApiOptions` to help Dagger understand that the value could be `null`, or you could create a general fallback here:

```java
private static final ApiOptions DEFAULT_OPTIONS = ApiOptions.builder()
    /* ... */
    .build();

/** Define a qualifier. You could also use @Named("defaults") etc. */
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public static @interface WithDefaults {}

@Provides
@WithDefaults
ApiOptions provideApiOptions(@Nullable ApiOptions options) {
  if (options == null) return DEFAULT_OPTIONS;
  return options;
}
```

Naturally, you could also do the reverse, using `@BindsInstance @Nullable @HasDefaults options` so you can inject an unqualified non-nullable ApiOptions where you need it:

```
@Qualifier @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) public static @interface HasDefaults {}

@Provides ApiOptions provideApiOptions(@Nullable @HasDefaults ApiOptions options) {
  if (options == null) return DEFAULT_OPTIONS;
  return options;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. If my understand is correct, in the `@Component.Builder`, setApiOptions will look like this `@BindsInstance @Nullable Builder setApiOptions(@WithDefaults ApiOptions options);`?

Comment: No, `@Nullable` would go on the parameter, ApiOptions options. If you go with the first style you would leave `@WithDefaults` off the Builder, but if you go with the second style you would put the annotation on the parameter along with `@Nullable`. (I used `@HasDefaults` just to distinguish them.)